# Calculating top-5 error rate in Caffe?

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I use synset for calculating sort top `k` predictions from softmax output.

Which gives me the top 5 class names. But I want to know how can I calculate its percentage. 
I mean the top-5% error.

Can anybody kindly guide me.
thanks.

Comment: it is unclear how you are using caffe exactly? Are you in training phase? what interface are you using?

Comment: I trained a bvlc_reference_Caffe model. Now trying to calculate its top-5 error. As you said there is a parameter top_k, But i dont know where to assign 5 instead of 1. I am also using ipython notebook Classifying script given with caffe.

Comment: in test phase there is little meaning to accuracy (you usually don't know in test time what the true label is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During training, you can compute the "top k" accuracy using "top_k" parameter to the accuracy layer. Here's an example modifying the existing accuracy layer in [bvlc_reference_caffe's `train_val.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt#L384):

```
layer {
  name: "accuracy_top_5"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy_top_5"
  accuracy_param {
    top_k: 5
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

Comment: let me check. will be back in few minutes

Comment: can i use both, I mean same accuracy layer and in addition a new layer accuracy_top_5. So that to take both top1 and top5.

Comment: @khan sure you can. you can have as many as you like. just give them different names and different tops

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thanks alot. But I am in confusion, Will it work for trained model, I mean if i change the train.prototxt and just check it once with final solver. To check final validation top-5 error